# Search an array for members of given sum?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array of numbers (or exactly floats with 2 decimal digits)

```
array(104.5, 2345.6, 16.7, 111.9, 900.01)
```

and a sum - for example 1004.51

How do I suggest members of this sum from he given array in PHP?

I want to have an array of to elements 104.5 and 900.01 at the end.

Thanks.

Comment: I had come across this question in Stack Overflow. There's definitely a dupe somewhere.

Comment: write the algorithm your trying to implement first

Comment: If you are looking for 2 numbers that make up that sum then that is a classical coding challenge, as you can see it [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/). The only difference is that it uses `int`s instead of `float`s